# Using regex to pull multiple matches out of a line

Tags: regex, vb.net, replace, split, matching

I seem to have entered a pretty complex area (to me anyways.)
Lets say I have the following line:

```
1:11:39 "LOGIN ATTEMPT: "47576966" Arlond"
```

What I am trying to do is seperate the time(1:11:39) ID(47576966) and name(Arlond). I got as far as the below regex but I am sort of lost at what I need to do next.  I understand my regex is incorrect to grab everything I need and that's where I'll also need help among getting my For loop to work correctly.  I have been looking up on how to regex split and replace but so far I have not had any luck getting anything to work.

```
([""'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1


Using TestFile As New IO.StreamReader(My.Settings.cfgPath & "tempRPT.txt", System.Text.Encoding.Default, False, 4096)
        Do Until TestFile.EndOfStream
            ScriptLine = TestFile.ReadLine
            ScriptLine = LCase(ScriptLine)
            If InStr(ScriptLine, "login attempt:") Then
                Dim m As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(ScriptLine, "([""'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1")
                For Each x As Match In m

                Next
                'builder.AppendLine(ScriptLine)
            End If

        Loop
    End Using
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to your regular expression, I've always found it best to be explicit wherever possible (anchors, for example).  Assuming your input data is as well behaved as it looks, you could do something like this:

```
^(\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s""LOGIN\sATTEMPT:\s""(\d+)""\s([^""]+)""$
```

Breaking that into its components:

```
^                       // Anchor: Start of string (or line).
(\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2})   // Capture one or two digits, colon, two digits, colon, two digits.
\s""LOGIN\sATTEMPT:\s"" // Anchor: match (but don't capture) literal text.
(\d+)                   // Match/capture one or more digits. (maybe you could use \d{8} instead).
""\s                    // Anchor: literal text.
([^""]+)                // Match and capture everything that is not a quote.
""                      // Anchor: Literal quote.
$                       // Anchor: End of string (or line).
```

This breaks down if your `name` field is allowed to contain the `"` (double-quote) character.  If that turns out to be the case you will have to modify the last subexpression to be more permissive.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming I can use char(34) rather than hard quotation marks inside the regular expression?

Comment: You should be able to use \x22 (or however your language prefers that you present the ASCII code or Unicode code-point representation of the literal character).

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I've broken it down in a crude way but it helps me learn how it all works.

Comment: Another possibility: I believe VB allows you to embed double-quote literals by doubling up on the double-quotes.  So `"\s` would become `""\s`, etc.

Comment: Yep, I had doubled up on the quotes and it works like a charm now.

Answer (score 1):

In response to DavidO's accepted question, I just wanted to show that I've broken it down to understand it better.

```
If InStr(ScriptLine, "login attempt:") Then
                Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(ScriptLine, ("(\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2})"))
                hurrburr = m.Value
                'Regex.Replace(ScriptLine, "(\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2})", "")
                Dim mm As Match = Regex.Match(ScriptLine, "(\d{7,8})")
                'ScriptLine = ScriptLine & " " & mm.Value
                hurrburr = hurrburr & " " & mm.Value
                Dim mmm As Match = Regex.Match(ScriptLine, """\s([^""]+)")
                temp = mmm.Value.Replace("""", "")
                hurrburr = hurrburr & " " & temp
                builder.AppendLine(hurrburr)
 End If
```